# How to install Cartes du ciel skychart?

Tags: installation

Running Oz Unity on laptop. I have installed Skychart and I want to install the UCAC4 astronomy catalog. There is only one problem. The program only comes in .exe format. Is there a way to convert it and run it with Debian package installer?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to convert the UCAC4 catalog in order to use it with Skychart. These catalog files are compatible for use within Ubuntu/Skychart as provided.

As you are probably aware, the catalog is available in three parts and can be downloaded from [here](http://www.ap-i.net/skychart/en/download).

Once you have downloaded the catalog, follow these steps:

1. Extract the file to your `~/Downloads` directory.
2. Move the `ucac4` and `ucac4-streak` folders to `/usr/share/skychart/cat`

   - `sudo mv ~/Downloads/ucac4 /usr/share/skychart/cat/ucac4`
   - `sudo mv ~/Downloads/ucac4-streak /usr/share/skychart/cat/ucac4-streak`
3. Follow the instructions [here](http://www.ap-i.net/skychart/en/news/ucac4_catalog) to add and activate the ACAC4 catalog within the Cartes du Ciel/Skychart application:

   - From within Skychart, open the menu `Setup -> Catalog -> Catalog`.

     [image]
   - Click the Add button and select the file `/usr/share/skychart/cat/ucac4/4uc.hdr`.

     [image]
   - Click on the first column to make catalog selection circle green.
   - Do not forget to save the default options.